# com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: Could not acquire new ID block from storage

Tags: titan

I am running a simple program

```
    TitanGraph bg = TitanFactory.open("/home/titan-all-0.4.2/conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties");
    IdGraph g = new IdGraph(bg, true, false);

    Vertex v = g.addVertex("xyz132456");

    g.commit();
```

Here there is no vertex `xyz132456` exist before but i am getting following exception. I am getting this exception very frequently. My titan server(0.4.2) is configured with all default settings as i am just testing simple operations with this.

```
253  [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.node  - [Chtylok] version[0.90.5], pid[4015], build[c8714e8/2013-09-17T12:50:20Z]
253  [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.node  - [Chtylok] initializing ...
260  [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.plugins  - [Chtylok] loaded [], sites []
2303 [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.node  - [Chtylok] initialized
2303 [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.node  - [Chtylok] starting ...
2309 [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.transport  - [Chtylok] bound_address {local[1]}, publish_address {local[1]}
2316 [elasticsearch[Chtylok][clusterService#updateTask][T#1]] INFO  org.elasticsearch.cluster.service  - [Chtylok] new_master [Chtylok][1][local[1]]{local=true}, reason: local-disco-initial_connect(master)
2325 [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.discovery  - [Chtylok] elasticsearch/1
2420 [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.http  - [Chtylok] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9201]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.0.5:9201]}
2420 [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.node  - [Chtylok] started
2987 [elasticsearch[Chtylok][clusterService#updateTask][T#1]] INFO  org.elasticsearch.gateway  - [Chtylok] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
3234 [main] INFO  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend  - Initiated backend operations thread pool of size 2
3542 [main] INFO  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration  - Configuring edge store cache size: 201476830
5105 [main] WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool  - Waiting for id renewal thread on partition 2 [1000 ms]
6105 [main] WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool  - Waiting for id renewal thread on partition 2 [2000 ms]
7105 [main] WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool  - Waiting for id renewal thread on partition 2 [3000 ms]
8106 [main] WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool  - Waiting for id renewal thread on partition 2 [4001 ms]
9106 [main] WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool  - Waiting for id renewal thread on partition 2 [5001 ms]
10106 [main] WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool  - Waiting for id renewal thread on partition 2 [6001 ms]
11107 [main] WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool  - Waiting for id renewal thread on partition 2 [7002 ms]
12107 [main] WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool  - Waiting for id renewal thread on partition 2 [8002 ms]
13107 [main] WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool  - Waiting for id renewal thread on partition 2 [9002 ms]
14108 [main] WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool  - Waiting for id renewal thread on partition 2 [10003 ms]
Exception in thread "Thread-4" com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: Could not acquire new ID block from storage
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool.renewBuffer(StandardIDPool.java:117)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool.access$100(StandardIDPool.java:14)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool$IDBlockThread.run(StandardIDPool.java:172)
Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.PermanentStorageException: Permanent failure in storage backend
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.convertException(CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.java:311)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.getNamesSlice(CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.java:196)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.getSlice(CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.java:120)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.idmanagement.ConsistentKeyIDManager$1.call(ConsistentKeyIDManager.java:106)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.idmanagement.ConsistentKeyIDManager$1.call(ConsistentKeyIDManager.java:103)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:90)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.idmanagement.ConsistentKeyIDManager.getCurrentID(ConsistentKeyIDManager.java:103)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.idmanagement.ConsistentKeyIDManager.getIDBlock(ConsistentKeyIDManager.java:159)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool.renewBuffer(StandardIDPool.java:111)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: TimedOutException()
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$multiget_slice_result$multiget_slice_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:11623)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$multiget_slice_result$multiget_slice_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:11560)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$multiget_slice_result.read(Cassandra.java:11486)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_multiget_slice(Cassandra.java:701)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.multiget_slice(Cassandra.java:685)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.getNamesSlice(CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.java:176)
    ... 9 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: -1
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:92)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool.nextBlock(StandardIDPool.java:88)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandardIDPool.nextID(StandardIDPool.java:134)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.VertexIDAssigner.assignID(VertexIDAssigner.java:269)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.VertexIDAssigner.assignID(VertexIDAssigner.java:155)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.assignID(StandardTitanGraph.java:226)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.addPropertyInternal(StandardTitanTx.java:521)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.setProperty(StandardTitanTx.java:552)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.addProperty(StandardTitanTx.java:495)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.addVertex(StandardTitanTx.java:345)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.blueprints.TitanBlueprintsTransaction.addVertex(TitanBlueprintsTransaction.java:72)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.blueprints.TitanBlueprintsGraph.addVertex(TitanBlueprintsGraph.java:157)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.blueprints.TitanBlueprintsGraph.addVertex(TitanBlueprintsGraph.java:24)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.wrappers.id.IdGraph.addVertex(IdGraph.java:131)
    at newpackage.CityBizzStarting.main(CityBizzStarting.java:24)
```

Comment: Are you getting this error while batch loading or something?  Would you say that Titan is under heavy load?

Comment: no my titan will have 4-5 vertices only. No batch loading

Comment: "If you persistently get this exception AND your cluster is not under a lot of load then it is indicative of a communication problem." https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/UbqJd8CHj_A/9f_UA5WtcL8J  could that possibly be part of your problem?

Comment: I am running it locally i.e. cassandra is in my local system.What are the solution to get rid off this? restarting system? sometimes in my app I get this exception:`NotifyUtil::java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)` I dont't think this is the problem cos even after this its running well

Comment: This likely means that Titan cannot connect to the server. This could be due to port conflicts, firewall settings, or other communication problems.

Comment: OK, I will have to check where is problem.

Comment: Are there any updates on this, we have the same problem

Comment: any port conflict? which cassandra version u r using?